# How to know which sector is selected in wheel

Tags: android

Using this example http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/   How to select a sector or know which selector selected

Comment: You might take a look at the `getAngle` method that's already provided in the sample.